# Android Studio destroy my project, how fix this?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * gradle plugin from the resource data it found. It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */
package com.google.android.gms.tasks;

public final class R {
    private R() {}

}
```

this words android studio genereted after updating, and delete all my code, classes and all activity 
http://prntscr.com/lbm72c
I dont know how to fix this problem, when I open everything deleting and set autogenerating words

Comment: check the source files itself, if they are still there on the hard drive, and check if their content is OK

Comment: Regardless of I also speak Russian, please use English only on this part of stackoverflow.

Comment: I once had same problem, but I can't remember how I fixed it. I think that there is something wrong with encoding. Also try to copy the project to different location, and open from there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android xml files are showing java code suddenly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568350/android-xml-files-are-showing-java-code-suddenly)

Comment: I had this problem after updating android studio, how this fact can help me undestand how to fix this problem, I use UTF-8 encoding.