# All my layout xml files became autogenerated files

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Yesterday everything on my app was working flawlessly but today when I opened Android Studio all the xml files were corrupt(?-not sure if this is the right term)

Every one looks like this

[image]

Comment: Similar problem: [Android xml files are showing java code suddenly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568350/android-xml-files-are-showing-java-code-suddenly)

Comment: Which Android Studio version are you using?

Comment: Android studio 3.2.1

Comment: same issue happened to me today and don't know what is the solution , when u get a solution please write it here

Comment: the only solution i could find was to pull my project from github and build it again ....

Comment: Same issue i found today...Android 3.2.1. my project is very hude. this is very disappointing. there is no solution for it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had face same issue today and below are few steps which i had done and i **got success** to resolve this issue.

***Just copy your project into another directory or change project location***. and open your project again this simple step works for me.

Few more steps which i had tried may be this one works for you.

*Delete all cache file from below location*

> C:\Users{your pc name}.gradle\caches
>
> C:\Users{your pc name}.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches

Sync you project gradle.

Hope this will help you. This kind of error is really frustrating.

Comment: YOU SAVED ME FROM HEART ATTACK !

Comment: @Mr.Af Thanks same happen to me when i faced this  should i get upvote?

Comment: I found one more way also. I will update answer soon. I found this is common problem after upgrading Studio

Comment: bounty started .i am waiting for one more way.